# arning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Tags: php

> Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. in C:\wamp64\www\loginsystem\includes\dbh.inc.php on line 9
>
> Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, boolean given in C:\wamp64\www\loginsystem\includes\signup.inc.php on line 7
>
> Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, boolean given in C:\wamp64\www\loginsystem\includes\signup.inc.php on line 8
>
> Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, boolean given in C:\wamp64\www\loginsystem\includes\signup.inc.php on line 9
>
> Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, boolean given in C:\wamp64\www\loginsystem\includes\signup.inc.php on line 10
>
> Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, boolean given in C:\wamp64\www\loginsystem\includes\signup.inc.php on line 11
>
> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\wamp64\www\loginsystem\includes\signup.inc.php:8) in C:\wamp64\www\loginsystem\includes\signup.inc.php on line 16

Guys this is the set of errors i am getting again and again can ayone guide me what does these error means and how to resolve them exactly i am still new at php and trying to know these errors please help me or guide me i have attached few photos where it shoes my code 
[image]

Comment: Please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), [read about how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and learn [how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Screenshots are not a good way to include code. Instead, type out what the screenshot says. Thanks!

Comment: Connection to database fails. Make sure you use the correct host and port when using mysqli_connect function.

Comment: Post code from signup.inc.php  and dbh.inc.php

Comment: Read the first error message carefully. What is it telling you? Could that error possibly cause all the others?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using wampp. try go command line on the bin folder with mysql.exe file. Test are you able to connect to that server in the first place.

mysql -uroot -h 192.168.1.### -P 3306 -p

-uroot -u is indicate user name. root is the user name to login your mysql server. Just change the root to correct user name.

Possibility
1. Remote server did not open for remote mysql connection.
2. Remote server firewall is not open the Mysql port for remote connection.
3. You have attempt too many time  with wrong password. So now your IP is been blacklist by the MySQL server itself.